# Property not displaying in inspector, even with [field: SerializeField]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, serialization, properties

I've started using `[field: SerializeField]` to serialize properties so they show up in the inspector, like so:

```
[field: SerializeField] public int foo { get; private set; }
```

However, when I add functionality to the the property, it stops working.

```
private int _bar;

[field: SerializeField] 
public int bar
{
     get { return _bar; }
     set 
     { 
          _bar = value;
          DoThing();
     }
}
```

The keyword field has a green underline with the following warning:

```
"field" is not a valid attribute location for this declaration. 
Valid attribute locations for this declaration are 'property'. 
All attributes in this block will be ignored.
```

This seems to be disabling the attribute altogether, meaning it doesn't show up in the inspector.

I've tried replacing it with `[property: SerializeField]` like it suggests, but this doesn't show up in the inspector, nor can I find anything about it online.

I'm aware that I can create a custom inspector that will display it, but it's a lot of extra effort for what I'm trying to do, and I want to avoid it if possible.

Is there a way to get a property like this to display in the inspector without a custom editor?

Comment: No, you can only serialize auto-properties this way (which basically internally have a backing field) ... otherwise you will need to rather serialize your `_bar` field instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't serialize properties in Unity.

Serialize your backing field "_bar" instead.  Or write a custom editor for that object type if you want more control in the inspector.

Comment: You **can** serialize properties ... but only **auto-properties** (which internally basically **have** a backing field) ;)